# regEx to transform tsql Insert on Update command

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

I'm not very skilled with regex, I was wondering if it was possible to use a regular expression to transform a string like

```
insert into tblTest (id,title,col1,col2) values (1,'test','test1','test2')
```

into

```
update tblTest set title='test',col1='test1',col2='test2' where id=1
```

btw, the insert query will not be always like the one I've written in the example, but the first id it will be always present

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be possible with regex if and only if the insert query always had the same number of values.  Since it doesn't, no, it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned T-SQL so you could use [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) on SQL Server 2008 to capture an "UPSERT" type command to avoid transformation or having 2 queries...?

Comment: i have two distinct queries, i think i'll have to write a little script to do this work :) thanks